# Installed ZuckerReports on SugarCRM CE - How do I run one of the demo reports?

Tags: report, sugarcrm

I have SugarCRM CE 6.5.5, and have just installed ZuckerReports 2.1.1, ZuckerReports2 Jasper 4.0.0, and ZuckerReports2 DemoPack.

I have jdk 1.7u21 installed, and it tests ok on the Zucker administration page.

I can see the ZuckerReports top level menu (On-Demand, Report Archive, JasperReports Templates, New JasperReports Template, Query Templates, New Query Template, Report and Query Parameters, etc).

The JasperReports Templates show several templates: Opportunities by Industry, Activity, Pipeline By Sales, Opportunities, Meeting Printout, Closed Deals, Opportunity History Detail.

I want to run one of these reports, but can't see any "run" button on any of the sugarcrm pages. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue but one of the programmer assisted me fix this. basically you might have version incompatibility. Install zucker 2.1.0 generate in 4.0 format using iReport